# priority_queue.push doesn't call push_heap

Tags: c++

I have make a test and it seems that priority_queue.push doesn't call push_heap as stated at
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/push

I can't see the reason. Is there something wrong with my container function?

Here is my example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<int>& container(std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>>& q)
{
    struct queue_aux : private std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>> {
        static std::vector<int>& container(priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>>& q)
        {
            return q.* & queue_aux::c;
        }
    };
    return queue_aux::container(q);
}

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>> queue;

    for (auto i : {1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 5})
    {
        queue.push(i);
    }

    std::cout << "underlying container:\n";
    for (auto& i : container(queue)) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "queue:\n";
    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        int n = queue.top();
        std::cout << n << ' ';
        queue.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And the output:

> underlying container:
>    9 7 5 1 6 3
>     queue:
>     9 7 6 5 3 1

There is an original order, an after push order and a top order.

Comment: cppreference is not a normative reference. The implementation of `priority_queue` will behave _as if it were_ implemented this way; it does not mean that it will explicitly call `std::make_heap` (it may be implemented in terms of some internal `__make_heap` or something).

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't call push_heap?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your example supposedly shows that `push_heap()` is not called? Is it because the two printed lines are different? A heap is not the same thing as a sorted list, so the difference is expected here, and that first line looks like a well-formed heap to me.

Comment: @user253751, @Frank Oh, I see; I can't say `push_heap` is not called, it behaves as it is actually called. Thanks. Should I delete the question?